# div background-image in codeigniter use for bootstrap half-slider

Tags: codeigniter, bootstrap-carousel

I want to use the bootstrap half-slider carousel and I am using codeigniter. In it, it used `<div>` with `background-image` instead of `<img>`, like this

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
```

In my view used it like this:

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('../assets/images/image1.jpg')"></div>
```

However, it doesn't show the image.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: is your assets folder in your main directory?

Comment: @wolfgang1983, my assets folder is outside application folder of codeigniter..

Comment: I would create a css file in the assets folder then add it to the head area  add that style in css there and should work.

Comment: @wolfgang1983, I actually have 5 images in the slider. Do you mean, I have to make 5 classes with different background images?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you have structured your view files, but the reason why the first one is working is probably because it have an absolute path for the image ('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One')

Try using an absolute path to you image in the assets folder. 
Instead of: 
`<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('../assets/images/image1.jpg')"></div>`

Try:

`<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('<?=base_url('assets/images/image1.jpg')?>')"></div>`